# Reading ahead while looping through a list

Tags: python, iterable

I have a list of text files which looks like:

```
page_text_list = ['.............', '.............','name: bill','name: bob','address: 123 main st','name : tim','address: 124' ,'main st','name:', '.......']
```

If I find a 'name:' in the string I want to read ahead to get the address for that name. However as you can see the pattern is inconsistent and its not always possible to assume that the next line contains the full address.

I wanted to loop through the list using a simple loop

```
for line in page_text_list:
```

But this seems inadequate for the job. What's the best approach here?

Comment: Could you please post a syntactically correct Python list? It's hard to guess how your actual data structure looks like. I cannot copy paste and play around with what we have currently.

Comment: How's this .....

Comment: You could loop over `iter(page_text_list)` and use `itertools.dropwhile` to modify the iterator the `for` loop calls next on. I find it hard to say more without having the concrete output you expect for the given list.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. What is your expected output when an address doesn't follow a name until after another name? Should both names return the same address, or the first one nothing? Please give your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get a list of all the lines following the `name: ...` line until the next `name: ...` line, you could do:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, takewhile

page_text_list = ['.............', '.............','name: bill','name: bob','address: 123 main st','name: tim','address: 124' ,'main st','name:', '.......']

def get_address(name):
    # we drop all the lines who aren't 'name: bob'
    it = dropwhile(lambda line: line != "name: " + name, page_text_list)

    try:
        next(it)  # we drop the 'name: bob' line 
    except StopIteration: # if the name wasn't found, we exhausted the iterator
        pass

    # we return all the following lines, while they don't contain 'name:'
    return list(takewhile(lambda line:"name:" not in line, it))
```

Output:

```
print(get_address('bill'))  # no address
# []

print(get_address('dude'))  # not in our list
# []

print('\n'.join(get_address('tim')))
# address: 124
# main st
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a range iterator based on the range of the list, like so:

```
for index in range(len(page_text_list)):
    if page_text_list[index].startswith('name'):
        do_lookahead(page_text_list[index+1:])

def do_lookahead(list_rest):
     for line in list_rest:
         if line.startswith('address'):
             return line
```